# How do I force any iframe content to appear on top if changed, without changing the attributes in the links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, target

How do I force any iframe content to appear on top if the content is changed as if the link had the `target="_top"` attribute...

**EXAMPLE 1:** Normally this code is what would be applied in a page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top!=self){
    top.location.replace(document.location);
    alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")
}
</script>
```

But I need to aply it to the iframe instead, and fire it **only** if the iframe is changed. How do I do that?

For example, I click on a link within the iframe, once that page changes URL then the iframe puts the page on `target="_top"` without having attributes for it in the iframe URL page, but the attributes for it should be from the iframe page itself.

---

**EXAMPLE 2:**

I have found a code that works as it should, the problem is only that it only fires when clicked on a button. Can I somehow make it to fire automatically when content of the iframe changes?

**JavaScript:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function(){
          document.getElementById('example-button').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var win = open('about:blank');
    var iframe = document.getElementById('example-iframe');

    setTimeout(function () {
        var body = win.document.body;

        body.style.padding = 0;
        body.style.margin = 0;
        body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
        iframe.style.padding = 0;
        iframe.style.margin = 0;
        iframe.style.width = '100%';
        iframe.style.height = '100%';
        iframe.style.border = 0;
    }, 100);

    win.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        document.getElementById('example-container').appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.position = '';
        iframe.style.padding = '';
        iframe.style.margin = '';
        iframe.style.width = '';
        iframe.style.height = '';
        iframe.style.border = '';
    });
});
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
  <button id="example-button">open in new window</button>

<div id="example-container">
    <iframe id="example-iframe" src="https://example.com/">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean if the iframe is changed?

Comment: For example, I click on a link within the iframe, once that page changes URL then the iframe puts the page on `target="_top"` without having attributes for it in the iframe URL page, but the attributes for it should be from the iframe page itself.

Comment: Uh, someone else might have to answer that for you.  Though I will go ahead and ask in their steed, is the protocal://domain:port of the site in the iframe the same as that of the parent page?

Comment: Hmmm... you may want to explain your line of thinking in more words, as it's unclear. AFAIK `top` and `self` refer to the window, not the document or the iframed document.

Comment: If something will work as if it had the `target="_top"` attribute, it means it will open in the same window replacing the old page.

Comment: Not certain what requirement is?

Comment: I think you're trying to do the opposite of [THIS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target). Idk if that can be done. Why not let the iframed page have it's own navigation logic, ie. when a clicked link matches some criteria (ie other domain) use that href with top.location.replace   (would still not work if containing page prevents it)

Comment: I have found a attribute that fires that function from a button, problem is I want it to fire automatically when iframe changes, not from button. Wait let me add the code

Comment: Here I now added the code that fires from a button, sadly I need to have it done automatically.

Comment: If this is cross-domain: Parent page has no access to anything inside the iframe (ie detect click). And code inside the iframe can't restyle it's own container. It can only attempt to open itself in the parent window, which is what the `top=self` does. Or as I suggested replace the window location. But I'll follow this and see if Derek comes up with anything useful...

Comment: After fiddling and putting together with loads of ideas given online by others I came up with a solution that is 70% correct.
Now the only thing that remains is how to make it react ONLY when the iframe URL changes and not when loading like now.

Comment: If you mean iframe src: it will not change when you click a link inside the iframe. There's something that can be done with iframe contents() and I think I recall you can get the location... but it will not work cross-domain. So, no next-gen iframe breaker yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling and putting together with loads of ideas given online by others I came up with a solution that is 70% correct.

Now the only thing that remains is how to make it react ONLY when the iframe URL changes and not when loading like now.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function GoToURL()
{
    var URLis;
    URLis = document.URLframe.u.value
    {
        var location= (URLis);
        window.open(location, '_blank');
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="URLframe" id="URLframe" method="post">

<iframe id="test" src="https://example.com" onload="GoToURL(this);"></iframe>
<input type="hidden" name="u" size="71" value="" placeholder=" URL " id="SeekBox" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)">

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  document.getElementById('SeekBox').value = document.getElementById('test').src;
})();
</script>

</form>
```

**To test it easier I used these codes at the bottom instead:**

```
<iframe id="test" src="https://www.4shared.com/privacy.jsp" onload="loadurl();" width="100%" height="528px"></iframe>


<input type="text" name="u" size="71" value="" placeholder=" URL " id="SeekBox">
<input type="button" id="SeekButton" onclick="GoToURL(this);" value=" go ">
<input type="button" id="SeekButton" onclick="loadurl();" value=" load url ">
<input type="button" id="SeekButton" onclick="alerturl();" value=" alert url ">

<script type="text/javascript">
function alerturl() {
  alert($('iframe').attr('src'));
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function loadurl() {
  document.getElementById('SeekBox').value = document.getElementById('test').src;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you want to get the src of the iframe any time there is a change within the iframe and then open a window with that src. If I'm right then it doesn't seem like it's possible. I tried to get the source of the iframe using this little bit of code but to no avail.

```
<iframe id="test" src="justanotherwebsite.com" onLoad="iframeLoad()"></iframe>
<script>

var counter = 0;
function iframeLoad(){
    if (counter > 0){
    console.log($('#test').attr('src'));
    }
    counter ++;
}

</script>
```

Let me know if I'm way off the mark on this and I'll have another look.

Comment: Your solution only prints it in an alert message. It should put it in the URL bar instead and ONLY if a change is made in the frame, not as now when it loads.

Comment: @SeekLoad Sorry I should have explained myself better... it’s not a solution. It’s just a test to see if we can get the src when it’s changed. Which we can’t. Clicking on any link within the iframe opens the alert again with the original url. Let me know if I’m wrong and I’ll delete answer.

Comment: But it gave me an idea. I have a solution to put URL from a text box, into a _blank new tab. So if I use that to it, then what I need is the same solution you gave, but instead of printing it to a alert message, it should get printed to a text box that is a `type="text"` box. Then by the use of my text box to URL address bar I can make the frame fire as a _blank page or _top page.

Comment: So is there a possibility to print the URL to a text box instead of an alert as you did?

Comment: @SeekLoad you can fire any function you define so you can do what you like with it really... I'll update the answer to show it logging to the console.

Comment: The idea behind your code is good but it does not work when I test it.

Comment: On the other hand I just made a code that works. wait 1 min so I post it.

Comment: It is not a complete solution, but it 70% half of the way.

Comment: Ha! Is that 35%?

Comment: LOL hahaha good joke. But lets be honest the solution I gave does load the iframe in a _blank new tab or in as a _top tab. The only problems remaining now is to have it fire only when the URL address of the iframe changes. Sadly the attribute `onchange` does not work with iframe like this.

Comment: Gave it a +1. I'm still perusing the internet for the other 30%.

Comment: @SeekLoad What about adding a counter? I’ll update the code in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158031/discussion-between-seekload-and-derek-nolan).